# Text doesn't appear when open View as sheet view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a custom Menu drop down written in SwiftUI:

```
//
//  DropDownMenuListCustom.swift
//  TLUPortal
//
//  Created by Thành Duy Nguyễn on 8/7/23.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

public struct DropDownMenuListCustom: View {
    @State var expand = false
    @StateObject var genderObject = TLUPortalPublishedVariables()
    
    public var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            VStack() {
                HStack {
                    Text(self.genderObject.selection_gender)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Image(systemName: expand ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.down")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 12, height: 6)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }.onTapGesture {
                    self.expand.toggle()
                }
                if expand {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Male")
                        self.expand.toggle()
                        genderObject.selection_gender = "Male"
                    }) {
                        Text("Male")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Female")
                        self.expand.toggle()
                        genderObject.selection_gender = "Female"
                    }) {
                        Text("Female")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                } // End of conditional
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [.blue, .purple]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        .cornerRadius(12)
        .animation(.spring())
        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
    }
}
```

And I use that custom menu drop down in `UserInfoView.swift`:

```
//
//  UserInfoView.swift
//  TLUPortal
//
//  Created by Thành Duy Nguyễn on 8/2/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct UserInfoView: View {
    /**
        * UNCOMMENT WHEN RELEASE!!
     */
    
    /* let login_struct: <LoginStruct> */
    
    private enum Field: Int, CaseIterable {
        case firstName
        case lastName
        case fullName
        case dateOfBirth
    }
    
    var imageName: String?
    
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    
    @State private var buttonPressed: Bool = false
    
    @State private var firstName: String = ""
    @State private var lastName: String = ""
    @State private var fullName: String = ""
    @State private var dateOfBirth: String = ""
    @State private var genderSelection: String = "Male"
    
    @State private var labelHeight = CGFloat.zero
    
    @StateObject var gender_object = TLUPortalPublishedVariables()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack {
                        // User image
                        Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                            .padding()
                        
                        Spacer().frame(height: 28)
                        
                        // HStack for first name and last name
                        HStack {
                            // First name
                            VStack {
                                // First name label
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer().frame(width: 18)
                                    
                                    // First name user input
                                    Text("First Name")
                                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                                }
                                .frame(height: 10)
                                
                                TextField(text: $firstName, prompt: Text("First name")) {
                                    Text("First name")
                                }
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                                .textFieldStyle(TextFieldStyleCustom())
                                .focused($focusedField, equals: .firstName)
                                .padding(12)
                                .frame(width: 210)
                                .toolbar {
                                    // Show hide keyboard button
                                    ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                                        Button(action: {
                                            focusedField = nil
                                        }) {
                                            Image(systemName: "keyboard.chevron.compact.down")
                                        } // End of ToolBar->Button
                                    } // End of ToolBarItem
                                }
                            }
                            
                            VStack {
                                // Last name label
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer().frame(width: 4)
                                    
                                    Text("Last name")
                                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                                        .padding(12)
                                }
                                .frame(height: 10)
                                
                                // Last name user input
                                TextField(text: $lastName, prompt: Text("Last name")) {
                                    Text("Last name")
                                }
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                                .textFieldStyle(TextFieldStyleCustom())
                                .focused($focusedField, equals: .lastName)
                                .padding(12)
                                .frame(width: 210)
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Spacer().frame(height: 20)
                        
                        // Full name
                        VStack {
                            // Full name label
                            
                            HStack {
                                Spacer().frame(width: 4)
                                
                                Text("Full name")
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                                    .padding(12)
                            }
                            .frame(height: 10)
                            
                            TextField(text: $fullName, prompt: Text("Full name")) {
                                Text("Full name")
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .textFieldStyle(TextFieldStyleCustom())
                            .focused($focusedField, equals: .fullName)
                            .padding(12)
                        }
                        
                        Spacer().frame(height: 10)
                        
                        HStack {
                            // Gender label
                            
                            HStack {
                                Spacer().frame(width: 4)
                                
                                Text("Gender: ")
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .padding(12)
                            }
                            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                            
                            // Last name user input
                            DropDownMenuListCustom(genderObject: gender_object)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                        }
                        
                        Spacer().frame(height: 21)
                        
                        // Date of birth
                        VStack {
                            // Date of birth label
                            
                            HStack {
                                Spacer().frame(width: 4)
                                
                                Text("Date of birth: ")
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                                    .padding(12)
                                    .frame(height: 16)
                            }
                            .frame(height: 10)
                            
                            Spacer().frame(height: 20)
                            
                            // Date of birth
                            TextField(text: $dateOfBirth, prompt: Text("Date of birth")) {
                                Text("Date of birth")
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 28)
                            .textFieldStyle(TextFieldStyleCustom())
                            .focused($focusedField, equals: .dateOfBirth)
                            .padding(12)
                        }
                    }
                } // End of ScrollView
            } // End if VStack
        } // End of NavigationView
    }
}

struct UserInfoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UserInfoView()
    }
}
```

And I called this view as Sheet view when press user icon and Tab View:

Here's the code will show my `UserInfoView.swift` as Tab View:

```
//
//  CustomTabView.swift
//  TLUPortal
//
//  Created by Thành Duy Nguyễn on 8/2/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct CustomTabView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    @State private var buttonPressed: Bool = false
    
    @EnvironmentObject var selectionObject:  TLUPortalPublishedVariables
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectionObject.selection) {
            MainView()
                .environmentObject(TLUPortalPublishedVariables())
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Main menu", systemImage: "list.dash")
                }
                .disableSwipeBack()
                .tag(Tab.MainMenu)
            
            UserInfoView()
                .environmentObject(TLUPortalPublishedVariables())
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Account", systemImage: "person.crop.circle")
                }
                .disableSwipeBack()
                .tag(Tab.UserInfo)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .disableSwipeBack()
    }
}

struct CustomTabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomTabView()
            .environmentObject(TLUPortalPublishedVariables())
    }
}
```

And sheet view when click User button, that code placed in `MainView.swift`:

```
//
//  MainView.swift
//  TLUPortal
//
//  Created by Thành Duy Nguyễn on 8/2/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var PortalLogin_Informations: TLUPortalPublishedVariables
    
    @EnvironmentObject var tabSelection: TLUPortalPublishedVariables // Use @EnvironmentObject directly
    
    @State private var buttonPressed: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer().frame(width: 20)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        buttonPressed.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                    }
                    
                    Text("Welcome back!")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                        .frame(height: 18)
                }
                .padding(6)
                
                Spacer().frame(height: 20)
                
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack {
                        Group {
                            // Row 1
                            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    Button("Press me") {
                                        print("")
                                    }
                                    .buttonStyle(CustomButton(imageName: "circle"))
                                    .cornerRadius(20)
                                    .padding(5)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .frame(width: 200)
                                    
                                    Button("Press me") {
                                        print("")
                                    }
                                    .buttonStyle(CustomButton(imageName: "circle"))
                                    .cornerRadius(20)
                                    .padding(5)
                                    .frame(width: 200)
                                }
                            }
                            // ...
                        } // End of group
                    } // End of ScrollView
                } // End of VStack
                .sheet(isPresented: $buttonPressed) {
                    NavigationView {
                        // Add image into UserInfoView()
                        UserInfoView().environmentObject(TLUPortalPublishedVariables())
                            .navigationBarTitle("Account")
                            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                                buttonPressed = false
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                            })
                            .buttonStyle(CloseButtonStyleCustom())
                    } // End of NavigationView of sheet
                } // End of .sheet()
            } // End of NavigationView
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is: When I open `UserInfoView.swift` as Sheet View, "Male" and "Female" text won't appear and (X) icon appear instead. But when I open `UserInfoView.swift`  as Tab View, "Male" and "Female" text appear correctly.

Here is the video will show the error, I will open `UserInfoView.swift` as Sheet View, then open in Tab View so that we can see different, any test will be run on my real machine (iPhone 11, iOS 16.6):

[image]

Here is the image, in case GIF too blur:

Sheet View:

[image: Sheet View]

Tab View:

[image: Tab View]

How can I make the Text render correctly when both case: Open in sheet view and tab view?

Comment: do not use `.environmentObject(TLUPortalPublishedVariables())` or multiple `@StateObject var ...`. Use **one** source of truth, 
  **@StateObject var genderObject = TLUPortalPublishedVariables()**, in your `struct YourApp: App {...}`
 then pass this model to the other views, using 
  `.environmentObject(genderObject)`. Currently you have many `TLUPortalPublishedVariables` that have no relations to each other.

Comment: Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)